# Open jQuery Fancybox in other page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have one link in page index.html and I need to open a div that is located in other page called index2.html but I can't do it.

My code is this:

Link in index.html

```
<a href="#modal" id="open-modal">Open Modal</a>
```

Content in index2.html page:

```
    <div id="modal" class="style-modal">                  
        <a id="close_modal" href="#" title="close modal"></a>
        <div id="content-modal">
          <p>Content here</p>
        </div>                  
    </div>
```

This is my code in efect.js:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#open_modal").click(function(){

            $( '#modal' ).fadeIn();
            $( '#bg-modal' ).fadeTo( 500, .5 );
         });

        $("#close_modal").click(function(){

            $( '#modal, #bg-modal' ).fadeOut();
        });
    });
```

Please help me.

Comment: Page 1 needs to control page 2, but how are these pages related? Unless page 1 opened page 2, or vice versa there is no link between them that you can use JS with. You could use your server to send a message from page 1 that Page 2 periodically checks for, but that is a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use window.location.hash:

Link in index.html:

```
<a href="http://example.com/index2.html#show-modal" id="open-modal">Open Modal</a>
```

Content in index2.html page:

```
<div id="modal" class="style-modal">                  
    <a id="close_modal" href="#" title="close modal"></a>
    <div id="content-modal">
      <p>Content here</p>
    </div>                  
</div>
```

This is my code in efect.js:

```
function showModal() {
    $( '#modal' ).fadeIn();
    $( '#bg-modal' ).fadeTo( 500, .5 );
}

$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#open_modal").on('click', showModal);

        $("#close_modal").click(function(){
            $( '#modal, #bg-modal' ).fadeOut();
        });
        if (window.location.hash == '#show-modal') {
            showModal();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to load a div from another page into the modal, try using AJAX like this:
**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/hwVrN/1/ 
**HTML**:

```
<a href="#modal" id="open-modal">Open Modal</a> 
<div id="modal-container">

</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#open-modal").click(function(){
            $('#modal-container').load('index2.html',function(){ 
                $( '#modal' ).fadeIn();
                $( '#bg-modal' ).fadeTo( 500, .5 );
            });
         });

        $("#close-modal").click(function(){

            $( '#modal, #bg-modal' ).fadeOut();
        });
    });
```